# Conditions for locally convex space to be normable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff locally convex space and $P$ is a family of seminorms on $X$. How to show that $X$ is normable iff $P$ is equivalent to a finite subfamily $P_0 \subset P$?
One implication is obvious, we can take as a norm maximum of subfamily $P_0$, but another implication isn't so trivial.

Comment: Is the family $P$ one that generates the topology on $X$? If so, let $p$ be a single norm generating the topology and find a finite subfamily to show $0$ is an interior point of the open $p$ unit ball. That finite subfamily will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, other implication is also trivial, suppose that $X$ is normable denote by p the norm, then $\exists p_1, \ldots p_n$ - seminorms, such that
$$ p \leq Cmax_kp_k$$
It's obvious that topology $\tau(p_1 \ldots p_n)$ is equivalent to the given topology, because for $p_j \in P$
$$p_j \leq C_j p \leq C_jCmax_kp_k$$